# The ALLMEMBERS function expects a hierarchy expression for the argument

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas

I am building a new report on a new cube - there is no existing working reports on this cube.

When I run the report from the SSRS web interface I get the following error:

error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'dsCubeGrossSales'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Query (1, 95) The ALLMEMBERS function expects a hierarchy expression for the argument. A member expression was used.

The report runs fine in preview mode from the SSRS Visual Studio development environment.

I can browse the cube through SSMS

This is the query in dsCubeGrossSales

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Home Gross], [Measures].[Home Net] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Dim Date].[Current Year].[Current Year].ALLMEMBERS * [Dim Division].[Division Groups].[Division].ALLMEMBERS * [Dim Branch].[Branch].[Branch].ALLMEMBERS * [Dim Branch].[Branch Name].[Branch Name].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Dim Date].[Current Year].&[0] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Finance Period Balance]) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

We have just upgraded everything to SQL 2014 and Visual Studio 2014

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

I had changed the [Current Year] label to [Current Fiscal Year] in the cube and didn't update the query.  It was confusing that I could run the report in Preview mode from SSRS.

Comment: The data is cached in SSRS; a refresh would probably break your report output.